# Callback for when a Notification is opened on an Android app

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilesdk, android

I am new to marketing cloud and after going through the documentation I haven't found anything similar to a callback for when the SalesForce notification is clicked.

In our project we also use the urbanairship sdk and they provide a callback for that, making it easier to sendo metrics related to that notification.

Is there something similar in the marketing cloud sdk?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `LaunchIntentProvider` into the SDK's initialization method or you can take complete control of the notification handling -- note, however, if you do the latter (using a `builder`) you will need to wrap your handling of the notification with `redirectForAnalytics()` in order for the Marketing Cloud to also collect the open events.

Ref. https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/notifications/customize-notifications.html